# Android ActionBarSherlock on NetBeans - working but editor showing errors

Tags: android, netbeans, actionbarsherlock

I'm using NetBeans for android application. I installed properly (I think) ActionBarSherlock package as android library project. Everything works fine, I can build and run application, but code editor doesn't recognize ABS classes (just look at screenshot, BUILD SUCCESSFUL but errors exists) and code completion doesn't work too.

My configuration:

- Stable NetBeans 7.2 with android plugin ver. 1.13
- Linux Mint 13 Maya 64 bit, Mate
- ActionBarSherlock ver 4.2 (stable)

How I installed ABS:

1. Download and extract source
2. From sdk/tools run command:

   ./android update project -p path_to_ActionBarSherlock/library/
3. Similar command to connect android project library with my test project (there is similar option in Netbeans IDE but I get error that this is not android library project)

   ./android update project -l path_to_ActionBarSherlock/library/ -p path_to_my_test_project

I have tried clean and build on both projects but no results. Any idea?

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The way I finally managed to add ActionBarSherlock to my android project on Netbeans was to:

1. Download the latest version of ActionBarSherlock and unzip it
2. Go to the subfolder called library and remove the pom.xml file from there (with one of the previous versions it didn't work. I had to first build it, close it and remove not only pom.xml but also some netbeans properties files)
3. Open that subproject (library) in the Netbeans

Now this project will no longer be seen as a maven project. Netbeans will see it as an Android project. Then I:

1. Clean&build it
2. Add it to my-project's library properties (right-click on my-project, properties, library, add, point the proper location of library project). Important here was to copy/move that library project somewhere near my-project. Otherwise it claimed that it cannot open it.
   And from now on it works fine.

Key to that thinking was that Netbeans didn't want to add the provided library project cause it saw it as a Maven project. When the pom is deleted, Netbeans no longer sees it as Maven project nut as an Android project and it can without any objections add it as an Android's project library.

Probably there are better solutions, but I didn't find any and that was the only one working for me.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a new Android project, and then copy and paste the needed files in the new project. 
So only copy:
libs, res, src, AndroidManifest.xml